# populate Text filed with value or placeholder laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I want to populate text field from database with value if it dose not equal to default column value. My default column value for `$event_date` is`'0000-00-00 00:00:00'`.

If `$event_date='0000-00-00 00:00:00'` then I want to use placeholder `Date`

```
@if($conversation->event_date!='0000-00-00 00:00:00')
  <div class="form-group">
   {{ Form::text('event_date', null, array('class' => 'form-control
   conversation-field')) }}
  </div>
 @else
  <div class="form-group">
   {{ Form::text('event_date', null, array('class' => 'form-control 
   conversation-field','placeholder'=>'Date')) }}
  </div>
 @endif
```

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

You should not escape when outputting HTML content so {!! and not {{

```
@if ($conversation->event_date != '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
  <div class="form-group">
   {!! Form::text('event_date', $conversation->event_date, array('class' => 'form-control
   conversation-field')) !!}
  </div>
 @else
  <div class="form-group">
   {!! Form::text('event_date', null, array('class' => 'form-control 
   conversation-field','placeholder'=>'Date')) !!}
  </div>
 @endif
```

Comment: not working text field is populated with  0000-00-00 00:00:00 not using placeholder

Answer (score 0):

In a simple yet neat way you'd do something like this:

```
  <div class="form-group">
   {{ Form::text('event_date', $conversation->event_date != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ? $conversation->event_date : null, array('class' => 'form-control
   conversation-field', 'placeholder'=>'Date')) }}
  </div>
```

Comment: its not working showing same 0000-00-00 00:00:00 not placeholder

Comment: Please tell me what is the output of `var_dump($conversation->event_date)`?

Comment: string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" after var_dump

Comment: Change `!=` with `!==` like this: `$conversation->event_date !== '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ? $conversation->event_date : null`

Comment: OK, try this: `preg_match("#0000-00-00 00:00:00#", $conversation->event_date) ? null : $conversation->event_date` replace this in my previous code and it will work. It is tested.